# How to know coordinates of java frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent, point

I am trying to develop a very basic game and it involves mouse. So what i am trying to do is getting coordinates of mouse to write a integer. I searched internet and find this.

```
mouse_x=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
mouse_y=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
```

It partially worked and gave me coordinates of mouse on desktop. But what i need is coordinates of mouse on frame. So if only i knew the coordinates of frame's starting (0,0) point (not the window's. the white area without toolbars.) I could calculate mouse's coordinates.
Thanks in advance.
Or if thats not possible i could use how to develop it in fullscreen.
And i need to know location of mouse always. It should refresh position when i run it in a never ending while loop.

Comment: See my edit in my answer. I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just use `e.getPoint()` which returns the point of the mouse clicked. You could either have your Frame implement `MouseListener` of you can register a `MouseListener` to the frame if it is not the main GUI component.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int x = (int) p.getX();
        int y = (int) p.getY();

        // do something withe the x and y points
    }
}
```

If you do the above, you also need to override the other `MouseListener` methods. Though you don't need to implement any action for them

```
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

If your GUI class didn't extend `JFrame`, then you can just register the listener to the Frame, in which case you only need to use the `MouseAdapter`, which allows you to just implement 0 or more action method (i.e. just `mouseClicked`)

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       Point p = e.getPoint();
       int x = (int) p.getX();
       int y = (int) p.getY();

       // do somthing withe the x and y points
   }
});
```

---

**Edit** for `MouseMotionListener`

> *"I want to know location of mouse always not just when clicked."*

If you wan't to know the location of the mouse at any given time, you should implement `MouseMotionListener` and override the `mouseDragged` and `mouseMoved`

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {

    ....

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int x = (int) p.getX();
        int y = (int) p.getY();

        // do something withe the x and y points
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

    }
}
```

The `mouseMoved` will fire an event every time the mouse is moved, and the `mouseDragged` will fire an event whenever the mouse is dragged

Comment: Thanks body that what i am looking for. and one more thing my class actually extends jpanel. so it gave me error when i implemented mouse listener.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's giving you an error because you need to implement both methods. when using the `MouseMotionListener`. Both `mouseDragged` and `mouseMoved`

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. You need to implement `MouseMotionListener`, not `MouseListener` I fixed it. Also, two `mouseMoved`s was a typo. You need both `mouseMoved` and `mouseDragged`

Comment: **MouseMotionListener** worked. Thank you body. :)  And i am sorry i could have been more clear on what i want.

Answer (score 4):

You need to  add a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to your JFrame and then you can just get the relative coordinates with `MouseEvent.getPoint`

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPoint());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, for some obscure reason, need the coordinates in a situation when mouse events are not available (in which case, take a look at the other answers), you can use [SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen%28java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29) to convert the coordinates from `MouseInfo` to the coordinate system of a `Component`.

Comment: I am not sure but thats what i am looking for. I want to know location of mouse always not just when clicked.

Comment: @OssoBuko It is usually the best to use the events, so that the position gets read only when the mouse position actually changes. I wrote my answer only for completeness so that if someone is looking for a solution for a situation where that's impractical, an alternate approach is on the same question page.